# In laravel when user is logged in and hit /login it redirects to root homepage

Tags: laravel, routes

In my laravel site, users can log in.
When a user is logged in, and hit `/login`, it redirects to root homepage at `/`.
I want this redirect to hit `/dashboard` instead of `/`.

The routes were created using make:auth.

This is a problem when im using WebView in my android app. The standard page in the android WebApp is /login - but if the user is logged in and then exits the app and open it again, they hit `/` instead of fx `/dashboard`.

**How do I redirect users from `/login` to `/dashboard`, if they hit `/login` while already logged in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I redirect users from /login to /dashboard, if they hit /login while already logged in?

At app/http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

       return redirect('/dashboard'); // redirect path wherever to redirect users when they already login
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your LoginController, set :

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
```